# I don't get an output when I compile a program having getchar(), etc on Linux Mint on the terminal window

Tags: c, linux, char, counting, getchar

I'm relatively new to Linux Mint and somewhat trying to get back at programming. I'm trying to learn this concept of reading, copying,counting using C Programming by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie.

I understood the concept of line counting, word counting etc but whenever I run the code, I don't get an output on the terminal window while I do when I used the online compiler at codechef.

Can someone explain why this is happening and the solution to it.

Thanks. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite = nother = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;
    }
    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",nwhite, nother);
}
```

Comment: and your code is....?

Comment: you need to show the code for us to spot your error. Or we can guess which line is the culprit. May be line 32. :D

Comment: I'm *really* curious as to why you think posting no details is acceptable.

Comment: Guys, Lets give the person some time to post the code before down voting or voting to close the question..

Comment: Please edit your question to add some code if you want help

Comment: @AmolSehgal, edit the question and post the code there.

Comment: Soory lads, I've posted the code now.. :)

Comment: initialize `int ndigit[10];` to `0`.

Comment: @Haris not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @Haris, initializing didn't help. Invalid initializer it says.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `EOF` in the line `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` with `\n`:

```
...
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
{
...
}
...
```

You are waiting on the "end of file" of the standard input stream which never will occur. instead you should wait on a "new line" character which basically represents the return button on your keyboard.

To make it clear to the user that he has to enter something you should ask the user with a further printf. Here the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count digits, white space, others */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
{
    int c = 0, i = 0, nwhite = 0, nother = 0;
    int ndigit[10] = {0};

    nwhite = nother = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    printf("Please enter any string and press [Enter]:\n");

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;
    }
    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",nwhite, nother);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm facing is I don't get an output when I run the code.

Replaced my lines with yours and still the same. No output as such.

Comment: @Amol Sehgal: I tried your code with the replaced line and for me it works. Of course you first to enter some characters and press return before you can see anything.

Comment: The return key typically returns Return (`\r`), not Line Feed (`\n`).

Comment: @gmug can u tell me how do i enter the characters on the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think this does?

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Here it seems like you want to execute the code until c == '\n'